# " bash: /usr/bin/mint-fortune: No such file or directory " - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, system-installation

Previously i used LMDE on my laptop, but now I moved to Ubuntu. I might have been a little bit rough with it, because I’ve simply format `/` partition, and installed Ubuntu on it. Home folder was separated, so i didn't touch it at all.

Now, when i start the Terminal, i get this message:

```
bash: /usr/bin/mint-fortune: No such file or directory
```

I've found a solution of this problem on Linux Mint forums:

```
sudo pico /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Removing the line:

```
/usr/bin/mint-fortune
```

But I don't have this line there. I imagine it has something to do with Home folder, since I formatted everything else before installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be on `~/.bashrc` file. So run this `gedit ~/.bashrc` command to open `.bashrc` file and then remove the line `/usr/bin/mint-fortune` from that. Atlast source the `.bashrc` file by running this command `source ~/.bashrc` so that the changes could be made permanent.

Comment: opening ~/.bashrc with sudo is bad

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the pest from kubuntu14.04 installation by editing with vim the last line of   /home/[my username]/.bashrc file, which line now looks as follows:

```
# remove this pest!  /usr/bin/mint-fortune
```

Before adding # it used to look simply as

```
/usr/bin/mint-fortune
```

which caused the error "not found" message to appear on the konsole

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 sudo apt-get remove fortune
```

I do not think that this has anything to do with your home folder, because the home folder typically just has user specific documents like music, photos, etc.

Sources:

[Removing Fortune Message](http://www.fettesps.com/how-to-remove-the-fortune-message-from-the-linux-mint-terminal/)

[Basic Linux Directory Structure](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxJJK1iZHTSfVlpQQklRZUNyTHM/edit)